# Генерирование new Exception без throws в cигнатуре метода

Tags: java, исключения

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему нельзя сгенерировать вручную исключение new Exception без добавления в сигнатуру метода throws? К примеру

```
void m() {
        throw new Exception(); //compilation error
    }
```

не компилируется. А если сгенерировать исключения любых производных от Exception классов, то код компилируется. К примеру

```
void m() {
        throw new NullPointerException(); // при вызове метода возвращает исключение
    }
```

Comment: не стесняетсь читать литературу, в частности про checked \ uncheked exceptions

Comment: О, вы наверное ещё удивитесь что есть ряд Error, который так же может всплыть "внезапно", у любого метода с невинной шапкой без throws

Answer (score 6):

Потому что все исключения делятся на 2 вида: checked (проверяемые) и unchecked (непроверяемые). Проверяемые исключения, как следует из названия, должны всегда обрабатываться пользователем (с помощью конструкции `try-catch`, либо пробрасыванием исключения далее за счет указания этого в сигнатуре метода). Непроверяемые исключения можно явно не обрабатывать.

К непроверяемым исключениям относятся классы `Error` и `RuntimeException` и все их наследники. Все остальные исключения - проверяемые.

В вашем случае второй пример компилируется, потому что `NullPointerException` - непроверяемое исключение.